# Javascript - Can I combine specific commands into one file and other commands in another?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently making a Discord bot via Javascript, but I want to cleverly clean up my code as there's too many 'else if' statements in my main.js file. For example, the beginning of the if statement is supposed to recall to a code that is an another file called 'ping'. But as opposed to doing this for each persons name in the form of an if loop, I just want to put this all in one file dedicated to names.

Currently, this is what my code on my main.js looks like:

```
    if (command === 'ping') { 
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'gaurav'){  
        client.commands.get('gaurav').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'will') {
        client.commands.get('will').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'michael') {
        client.commands.get('michael').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'jorin') {
        client.commands.get('jorin').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'reid') {
        client.commands.get('reid').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'emily') {
        client.commands.get('emily').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'eildert') {
        client.commands.get('eildert').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'julian') {
        client.commands.get('julian ').execute(message, args);
    }
```

In the "ping" file, I have

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "this is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
}
```

And I have these files for other peoples names listed above. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: No need for all those if/else. When you find yourself duplicating the same thing over and over it can be simplifed to something like  ... `if(isValid(command)){ client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);}`.  Up to you do create array of valid ones and a function `isValid()`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this...

Create an array to store a list of the valid names:

```
let names = [
    'ping',
    'gaurav',
    'will',
    'michael',
    'jorin',
    'reid',
    'emily',
    'eildert',
    'julian'
];
```

Then you just have to check if there is a name you want in that array. Do that by creating a variable that will hold the name you want to check for:

```
let checkForThisName
```

You'll have to assign `checkForThisName` to the name you want to check for. There are different ways you can do this.

Then check the array for the `checkForThisName`

```
if (names.includes(checkForThisName)) {
    client.commands.get(checkForThisName).execute(message, args);
};
```